# Why is a checkbox's click handler not fired in FF, when its label is shift clicked?

Tags: javascript, events, firefox

With the following code, when shift clicking the label, why isn't the checkbox's click handler fired in FF? Both Chrome and IE11 fires it.

```
<script>
    function show(event) {
        alert((event.srcElement||event.target).id);
    };
</script>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" onclick="show(event);" />
<label for="checkbox" id="label" onclick="show(event);">Click me!</label>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/66XP4/2/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Shift-clicking has a different default action than just clicking in Firefox.  The former extends the text selection.  The latter performs activation.  Since activation is what fires the click on the checkbox, you're not getting a click on it.  Just like you don't with a right-click on the label.

Comment: Oh, now I see the Firefox developers' reason: they wanted to make label's text selection possible, without activating the checkbox. But it was already possible just like in the case of links: by starting the selection by clicking below or above the text. I agree the FF method is more comfortable, but ignoring the specification this way indirectly leads to worse UX, through browser-incompability... But it's a whole different question, so thank you for the explanation. :)

Answer (score 2):

Probably because shift-clicking the label doesn't toggle the checkbox in Firefox?

Comment: Okay. But is it a bug, a non-standard behaviour or something that browser vendors can control freely? Should I send a bug report and wait for a fix, then update my code? Or should I simply circumvent it, and make my code more complex? I believe browsers should behave the same way in basic situations like this, to save us from writing triple as long codes for browser-compatibility. It's 2014.

Comment: err, why does it matter?  afaik, no spec mentions what should happen when shift-clicking built-in elements.

Comment: It matters just because I want to make future proof code. If differences like this are normal in browsers' behaviours, I suppose I need to use jQuery instead of having to constantly check if my workarounds are still needed, or the browser vendor changed his mind. In case things like this are considered as bugs, I'd better report it. Now I see there is no generally accepted view in this topic, so I need to make this decision on my own. Thank you for your help though!

Comment: Based on your answers, I suppose the right answer is something like this: "Beacuse there are no specifications for browser vendors to follow, regarding the behaviour of shift clicking a checkbox's label element." Am I right?

Comment: something like that.  i'm curious why you're so concerned about shift-click behavior in the first place though

Comment: "The label element's exact default presentation and behavior, in particular what its activation behavior might be, if anything, should match the platform's label behavior." - [(W3C's HTML5 Recommendation)](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-label-element)  

Shift clicking a checkbox's label on my platform checks the checkbox, so it should be cheked in FF as well, based on the recommendation. It's sad that they don't follow recommendations, but it doesn't seem to be a bug. Still, I will ask them to change this behaviour.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your comment. If I can solve this specific shift clicking problem, **I can reuse the same method** during my career to "make the world better"... I just simply ignored these kinds of problems, but I see browsers won't get better if people don't make them better. And it wastes a lot of time. (My time, other developer's time.) I don't want to constantly rewrite my code, nor make efforts for browser compatibility: I want them to know that there is a real need behind the recommendations.