# How can I passthrough a shift+click event to underlying input element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox, dom

For `<input>` wrapped in a `<label>` tag (e.g., `<label> <input type="checkbox"> Some Text </label>`), click events on `<label>` tag are also received by the `<input>` tag.

However Firefox will not pass the click event to `<input>` if shift key was also pressed while clicking on the `<label>` (other browsers work fine). As answered in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24092993), this is a Firefox specific behaviour.

Is there a way to turn this off (or override) in Firefox, so that shift+click events are received by `<input>` when a shift+click happens on `<label>`?

Comment: Use stopPropagation. it stops the event from bubbling up the event chain. This is help you or i don't understand the question?

Comment: @VikrantChaudhary Did you manage to check the answer?

Comment: @Dekel Yes, I did. But I ended up implementing it a bit differently for my use case. Thanks for answering!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `firefox` prevent this you will need to create this behavior yourself.

Here is a quick example (note that you might need to add/change things due to the `shift` key:

```js
function show(event){
  el = event.srcElement||event.target;
  if (el.nodeName == "LABEL") {
    event.preventDefault();
    ev = new Event('click');
    document.getElementById(el.getAttribute('for')).dispatchEvent(ev);
  } else {
    el.checked = !el.checked;
    alert((el).id);
  }
}
document.getElementById('checkbox').addEventListener('click', show, false);
document.getElementById('label').addEventListener('click', show, false);
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox"/>
<label for="checkbox" id="label">Click me!</label>
```

Comment: I ended up implementing it a bit differently for my use case. But thanks for answering!